# 3d graphics library that works with lowend video card(without pixel shader)?

Tags: 3d

Would like to know options in 3D graphics engines out there that can even work on cards that do not have support for pixel shader or dedicated video memory.

For example , xna samples do not work on my notebook ( no dedicated video memory , shared video memory(64MB) and no pixel shader )

Although , on this very notebook unreal tournament ( first version ) runs smooth.

I know OpenGL is one option and can be used in C# via interop.

Are there other choices one could consider fr developing 3d apps that run on low-end hardware ?

**Update #1:** Preferred development platform - dotNet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectX is still pretty good about supporting low-end hardware.  Of course, you won't be able to use advanced features like pixel shaders if your hardware doesn't support them, but it can emulate a lot of features (including hardware T&L) in software.

If you're using C#, you'll want to look into Managed DirectX.  As a start, MSDN has an article introducing the technology [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164112.aspx).

Comment: Isn't XNA the new name for latest in direct x ( version 10 i think ) ?

Comment: Nope, XNA is a sort of middleware library that sits between your application and DirectX in the application stack.  It provides a simplified interface to DirectX, as well as performing some additional game-engine type functions.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenGL-ES](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/) is intended for low end cards / cell phones

Answer (score 0):

You can either use openGL or DirectX.

DirectX has a managed library you can use from C# or you can [use PInvoke to pass window id from C#](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dhelper/archive/2008/11/24/how-to-render-managed-net-form-using-native-directx.aspx) to native C++ DirectX.

Both DirectX & OpenGL have support for older graphic cards that doesn't have pixel shader suppport.

Answer (score 0):

[Pixomatic](http://www.radgametools.com/pixomain.htm) is designed specifically as a drop in software replacement fo DX9. However, it's not free.